# Using Moose, how do I set the value of a 'ro' Attribute Trait, in runtime?

Tags: perl, attributes, metaprogramming, moose, traits

I've got an Attribute Trait that I want to set on the basis of other class attributes. I realy want a default on an Attribute Trait that gets a copy of the class `$self` and not the meta for the attribute. I want to do something like this in my class:

```
after 'BUILD' => sub {                                                     
  my $self = shift;                                                        
  $self->meta->get_attribute('id')->column_name( $self->_unique_key_name );
};
```

But, I want to keep my attribute trait RO? Is this possible. I know the MOP allows one to set the value of a class-attribute, but I can't figure out how to set an attribute on the meta-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really odd design (why would a metaclass need an instance of a class it is describing?) -- but you can do this easily enough by using the metaclass of the metaclass (remember that Moose meta classes are bootstrapped using the MOP itself):

```
$self->meta->meta->get_attribute("foo")->default($some_value);
```

Also remember that defaults need to be wrapped in a coderef if they are references themselves: `$some_value = sub { $instance };`

---

Actually, this won't work - 'default' is read only.  Rather than fiddling with the MOP at such a low level, I would urge you to reconsider your design - e.g. store your 'default' in another attribute, and writing a default sub that delegated to it:

```
package MyApp::Meta::Attribute::Trait::Foo;

# set at runtime, when we have an instance to store here
has _default_of_foo => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Object',
);
has foo => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Object',
    lazy => 1,
    default => sub { shift->_default_of_foo },
);
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this implimentation. Is it possible that [`->default` is readonly](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Class-MOP-1.11/lib/Class/MOP/Attribute.pm#Informational)

Comment: Right, but that doesn't explain the underlying question. What if `default` needs to get access to `$self` (class) the `shift` there isn't the object instantiated from the class that uses the attribute. It's some obscure meta for the attribute.

Comment: @Evan: so you want to go from the meta class to finding all instances of it? MooseX::InstanceTracker can do this, but I thought you would be assigning this value into your metaclass manually after you had an instance that you wanted to hang on to.

Comment: I'm not sure... I have a class which represents a table, it provides for a `_table_name`... If that class composes a role (namely `SurrogateKey`) it will inherit the provided attribute `id`, which has that attribute trait `DB_Col` (providing `column_name`), now I want `DB_Col`'s `column_name`, when used in `SurrogateKey` to default to the `table_name + '_id'`, which is found in the Class.